# Django custom manager get_queryset() not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I can't make my custom manager work...

```
class PublicArtigoManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublicArtigoManager, self).get_queryset().filter(data_publicacao__lte=timezone.now()).filter(permissao__lte=3)

class Artigo(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()
    publics = PublicArtigoManager()
```

when I test in the shell, It doesnt work

```
>>> from artigos.models import Artigo
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> print Artigo.objects.count()
9960
>>> print Artigo.publics.count()
9960
>>> print Artigo.objects.filter(data_publicacao__lte=timezone.now()).filter(permissao__lte=3).count()
9959
```

`Artigo.publics.count()` should return 9959, right? Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: What version fo django are you using? It was get_query_set at one point. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: Yea I saw that in the DOC, but i'm using 1.5.0

Comment: >>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 0, 'final', 0)

Comment: Timezone issues? Try examining `timezone.now()` in the manager and in interactive console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is the `get_query_set` method. [This is the doc for version 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/) managers and it says:

> You can override a Manager‘s base QuerySet by overriding the Manager.get_query_set() method. get_query_set() should return a QuerySet with the properties you require.

Try to do it with `get_query_set` instead of `get_queryset` which is how it is explained in the [dev doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

> You can override a Manager‘s base QuerySet by overriding the Manager.get_queryset() method. get_queryset() should return a QuerySet with the properties you require.

If you want to be 100% positive about how the method is named in your version just go to your `Manager` class definition in `django/db/models/manager.py` and search how is named the method in the class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Although I don't like this change. It's a breaking change in Django and even worst, fails silently. If that stays we will see a lot of questions like that here in SO! lol :)