# Permanently specify using for a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The query I do is:

```
Language.objects.using('avails').all()
```

How would I permanently specify this in the model itself, so I can just do `Language.objects.all()` ?

Comment: have you tried override the get_queryset of manager?

Comment: This might be useful: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/06/15/django-ditch-objectsusing-in-favor-of-a-per-view-decorator-to-switch-databases.html

Comment: @PauloPessoa I tried doing that, but unsuccessfully. It seems like it checks for the `db` before doing the queryset (at least when I tried).

Comment: If it doesn't cause any issues, you could just re-name that database to 'default' (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset)

Comment: @mfcovington - right but this isn't my default database. I have to use that for something else.

Comment: Using django database router you can select which database should be used for any model. Here is a good usage example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a model manager that would be much simpler to use than routers for a single model. Note the using of `get_query_set` instead of `get_queryset` (from [Django custom manager get_queryset() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468571/django-custom-manager-get-queryset-not-working)) --

```
class AvailsDBManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(AvailsDBManager, self).get_query_set().using('avails')

class Language(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    objects = AvailsDBManager()
```

Now instead of 50+ lines of code in multiple files, including modifying the settings, you can specify it directly in the model.

Comment: As far as I remember there were some problems with this approach like chaining db requests. Does this manager work well in queries like
`Language.objects.filter(code='en')`

Comment: @Nick it seems to work ok, here's an example: `>>> from apps.main.models import *
>>> Language.objects.filter(code='en')
[<Language: English>]`

Comment: it seems that for your case it's a better sollution to override models.Manager instead of dealing with routing. Database routing provides a vast range of flexibility but requires more time to get configuration done.